# JSON-String in PHP Array index 0

Tags: php, json, angularjs, zend-framework, mamp

Hello i have a problem since my Mamp Pro upgrade an the new PHP 5.3.29 Version on my MacOS Dev-System.

I use AngularJS in the Browser and send my Form-Data with PUT/POST-Request to the Server.

POST-Request:

`{"checklistentyp":"SB Rollout","anzahl_filialen":"12","kam":"1","kb":"1"}`

On Server-Side i use PHP 5.3.29 width ZendFramework 1.12.8 and RESTful
When i dump the Request-Data:`var_dump($this->_request->getParams());`

I have my JSON-String in a Array on index 0

```
array(5) {
 ["module"]=> string(3) "api"
 ["controller"]=> string(10) "checkliste"
 ["action"]=> string(4) "post"
 ["format"]=>string(4) "json"
 [0]=>string(73) "{"checklistentyp":"SB Rollout","anzahl_filialen":"12","kam":"1","kb":"1"}"
}
```

My Prodserver with Linux and PHP 5.3.10 don't have this Problem and all works.

Before the Upgrade to an new MAMP-Version all works fine on my MacOS Dev-System.

**Update:**
With PHP 5.3.14 the same Problem. I use for RESTful this Library https://github.com/codeinchaos/restful-zend-framework

**Update 2:**
I think i found the problem. When i do this:

```
$fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$cp = $fc->getRequest()->getHeader('Content-Type');
var_dump($cp);
```

The dump output is `bool(false)`

So i think the Problem is between Zend and PHP. The context-Switcher in the RESTful library can't detect the Content-Typ and return the raw body. Any Idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you send the object as-is? or you json-encode it explicitly?

Comment: If you send the object as-is, it will automatically send application/json header. If you encode it you will send it as a string (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) - check if that's happening

Comment: In JS i don't encode JSON, because i use AngularJS. I think the Problem is one the Server Side. On Server i use this RESTFul extension: https://github.com/codeinchaos/restful-zend-framework

Comment: The MimeTyp of the Request is application/json

Comment: In your output above, I see ["REQUEST_METHOD"] => string(3) "GET". Your original question was that this was a POST. Perhaps you are getting multiple requests (404 or OPTIONS request?) and are confused about which is which?

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake. The Workaround works. On PUT-Request i have a $_SERVER['Content-Type']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PHP bug in Mac OSX which is currently open. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66606&thanks=6

Zend Framework, in certain environments is affected, because the bug prevents the header type to being determined properly. restful-zend-framework depends on $fc->getRequest()->getHeader('Content-Type') method to determine response. See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5705. This document includes a work-around.

Adding the following code to public/index.php should fix.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])
   && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'])
) {
   $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] = $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];
}
```

Comment: Now i have install PHP 5.3.14 in MAMP and Copy the php.ini from production to this Version. But i have the same Problem

Comment: Always good to confirm php.init settings are correct. It looks like Zend may be the problem. See this bug: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5705

Comment: Yes, some workarounds can be found at bottom of http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5705. I'd probably work around it and wait for bug to be fixed (or fix it yourself).

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66606&thanks=6. I'll update the answer.